# Create new variable based on a condition across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, r-factor

I have a binary variable ("Penalty") and 30 factors with the same levels: "Discharge", "Suspended", "Fine", "Community order", and "Imprisonment".

A small example:

| ID | Possession | Importation | Production | Penalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fine | NA | Fine | Yes |
| 2 | NA | NA | Community order | No |
| 3 | Discharge | Discharge | NA | No |
| 4 | NA | NA | Suspended | Yes |
| 5 | Imprisonment | NA | NA | No |
| 6 | Fine | NA | Imprisonment | No |

I would like to create a new factor based on the same condition across these columns plus the binary variable and where there are differing levels in the same row would like the new variable 'sentence' to retain the levels with this priority: Imprisonment > Community order, Suspended > Fine > Discharge. e.g. Discharge will only be present in the new column where no other level appears.

Desired output:

| ID | Possession | Importation | Production | Penalty | Sentence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fine | NA | Fine | Yes | Fine |
| 2 | NA | NA | Community order | No | Community order |
| 3 | Discharge | Discharge | NA | No | Discharge |
| 4 | NA | NA | Suspended | Yes | Suspended |
| 5 | Imprisonment | NA | NA | No | Imprisonment |
| 6 | Fine | NA | Imprisonment | No | Imprisonment |

This is what I have attempted: (where "vec" is a vector of the factor column indices)

```r
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    crim_sanct = case_when(
      (if_any(vec) == "Discharge") ~ "Discharge",
      (if_any(vec) == "Fine") | (data$Penalty == "Yes") ~ "Fine",
      (if_any(vec) ==  "Suspended") ~ "Suspended",
      (if_any(vec) ==  "Community order") ~ "Community order",
      (if_any(vec) ==  "Imprisonment") ~ "imprisonment"))
```

Comment: Is `Penalty` only used with `Fine`?

Comment: Yes, it's `Fine` in any of the factor columns OR `Yes` in the Penalty column

Comment: So why is it then `Suspended`? The is a `yes` in Penalty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right direction but have some small syntax issues in `if_any`.

Also in `case_when` you need to put the conditions based on the priority. So if `Imprisonment > Community order` then `Imprisonment` condition should come first before `Community order`.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    crim_sanct = 
      case_when(
      if_any(Possession:Production, ~. ==  "Imprisonment") ~ "imprisonment",
      if_any(Possession:Production, ~ . == "Discharge") ~ "Discharge",
      if_any(Possession:Production,  ~. ==  "Suspended") ~ "Suspended",
      if_any(Possession:Production, ~. == "Fine") | (Penalty == "Yes") ~ "Fine",
      if_any(Possession:Production, ~. ==  "Community order") ~ "Community order")
)
data

#  ID   Possession Importation      Production Penalty      crim_sanct
#1  1         Fine        <NA>            Fine     Yes            Fine
#2  2         <NA>        <NA> Community order      No Community order
#3  3    Discharge   Discharge            <NA>      No       Discharge
#4  4         <NA>        <NA>       Suspended     Yes       Suspended
#5  5 Imprisonment        <NA>            <NA>      No    imprisonment
#6  6         Fine        <NA>    Imprisonment      No    imprisonment
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know how to handle the `Penalty` column, we ignore it for now. Creating a column `Sentence` based on the columns `Possession`, `Importation` and `Production` could be done with

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(across(
    Possession:Production,
    ~ factor(.x, 
             c("Imprisonment", "Community order", "Suspended", "Fine", "Discharge"),
             ordered = TRUE))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Sentence = min(c_across(Possession:Production), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     ID Possession   Importation Production      Penalty Sentence       
  <dbl> <ord>        <ord>       <ord>           <chr>   <ord>          
1     1 Fine         NA          Fine            Yes     Fine           
2     2 NA           NA          Community order No      Community order
3     3 Discharge    Discharge   NA              No      Discharge      
4     4 NA           NA          Suspended       Yes     Suspended      
5     5 Imprisonment NA          NA              No      Imprisonment   
6     6 Fine         NA          Imprisonment    No      Imprisonment
```

The main idea here is creating ordered factors and using a rowwise `min`-function to get the sentence with the hightest priority.

### Data

```r
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Possession = c("Fine", 
NA, "Discharge", NA, "Imprisonment", "Fine"), Importation = c(NA, 
NA, "Discharge", NA, NA, NA), Production = c("Fine", "Community order", 
NA, "Suspended", NA, "Imprisonment"), Penalty = c("Yes", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No")), problems = structure(list(row = 6L, 
    col = "Penalty", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", 
    file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Possession = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Importation = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Production = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Penalty = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```